How can i, set number an inside image center?
I need to ensure that an image is centered number in an HTML email. While the HTML code works correctly in a Chrome browser, I need help with making it display correctly in an email client.
I am give code,i am using php mailer -- mail.php file below showing
Body =`<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <p style="color:#181C32; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom:13px">
    What’s next?</p>
  <div style="background: #F9F9F9; border-radius: 12px; padding:35px 30px">
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width:40px; height:40px; margin-right:13px;position: relative;">
        <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
        <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">1</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">Complete your account</a>
          <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top:3px; margin:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Lots of people make mistakes while creating paragraphs Some writers just put whitespace in their text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="separator separator-dashed" style="margin:17px 0 15px 0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width:40px; height:40px; margin-right:13px;position: relative;">
        <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
        <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">2</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">Communication Tool</a>
          <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top:3px; margin:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Craft a headline that is both informative and will capture readers’ improtant attentions</p>
        </div>
        <div class="separator separator-dashed" style="margin:17px 0 15px 0"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width:40px; height:40px; margin-right:13px;position: relative;">
        <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" />
        <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">3</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">Task Planner</a>
          <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top:3px; margin:0;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Use images to enhance your post, improve its flow, add humor, and explain complex topics</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  
</td>
</tr>
</table>`

enter image description here
When sending an HTML template via email, I've noticed that the polygon-shaped image with a number inside is misaligned. How can I ensure that the number inside the image is centered correctly in the email?

Why do you tag PHP? Your problem is only styling, right?

we sent html code mail thats why we using php mailer using

email clients are notoriously behind browsers on implementing modern CSS. Use e.g. https://www.caniemail.com/ to check every property to see whether the email clients you are having to support work with that property or not. An example is flex - not apparently supported on GMail or on Windows Outlook.

You should inline the CSS and avoid certain HTML and CSS properties that may not be supported.
Here are the changes I made:

Moved styles directly into the style attributes.
Used tables for layout to ensure compatibility across various email clients.
Removed properties that are often unsupported in email clients, such as border-radius on divs.

<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <p style="color:#181C32; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; margin-bottom:13px;">What’s next?</p>
      <div style="background: #F9F9F9; border-radius: 12px; padding:35px 30px;">
        
        <!-- First Item -->
        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 17px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
              <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; display: block;">
              <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">1</span>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 13px;">
              <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;">Complete your account</a>
              <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top: 3px; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Lots of people make mistakes while creating paragraphs. Some writers just put whitespace in their text.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <!-- Second Item -->
        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 17px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
              <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; display: block;">
              <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">2</span>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 13px;">
              <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;">Communication Tool</a>
              <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top: 3px; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Craft a headline that is both informative and will capture readers’ important attentions.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <!-- Third Item -->
        <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 40px; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
              <img alt="container" src="https://example.com/assets/mail/icon-polygon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; display: block;">
              <span style="position: absolute; color: #50CD89; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">3</span>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 13px;">
              <a href="#" style="color:#181C32; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: none;">Task Planner</a>
              <p style="color:#5E6278; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding-top: 3px; margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Use images to enhance your post, improve its flow, add humor, and explain complex topics.</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


The image an number inside not center, instead, it to misplaced. came via mail not working

@ArunachalamA While testing, it was already centered, but you can adjust it as needed. I've already pointed out the changes I made.

@ArunachalamA My answer is to guide you in the right direction.

@ArunachalamA, share your mail code as well. There may be room for improvement or something that needs attention. Also, can you share the raw output of the received email?
